# How do i find a file in Windows cmd that is not owned by Administrator?

Tags: windows, cmd, directory, find

Currently i am using dir, 
dir c:\path*.* /s /q | find -i "Administrator"
this gives me the files owned by Administrator, how do i modify the command so it gives me an output of files not owned by Adminstrator? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to show the lines where there's no match, just add /v, from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find)

> /v Displays all lines that don't contain the specified string.

but that will show you the lines about directories and size. As mentioned by   @aschipfl barebones format don't contain owner information, I also can't find an alternative to show the barebones file path with the owner information. Since files might contain "Administrator", you'll want to specify"BUILTIN\Administrator" instead. So your command becomes

```
dir c:\path\*.* /a-d /s /q | find /i /v "BUILTIN\Administrator"
```

Comment: I can't believe that this is the solution unless you remove the `/B` switch from `dir`. Furthermore, I'd use `find /I /V "BUILTIN\Administrator"` (or similar) so a file containing `Administrator` in its *name* doesn't match…